# Use of the expression "have to" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, expressions, meaning-in-context

***Tasting Mediterranean cuisine is a “have to” plan in Oia***

Is that expresion correctly used in this sentence, or is it wrong?

Comment: It's not actually **used**; rather, it's **mentioned** -- that's what the quote marks are for. See [the `Use-mention` distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use–mention_distinction). Mentioned phrases are reified and may have no, or only a very distant, relation to their use. And they have completely different grammar. So it's fine. However, you must not pronounce _"have to"_ with a /v/. It must be pronounced /'hæftu/, with an /f/, in order to mean what you want it to mean.

Comment: Not in my idiolect, John.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds strange. I think people would get your meaning, but the idiomatic way to say this would be:

> A plan for tasting Mediterranean cuisine in Oia is a “must have".

I think that is probably the idiom you were going for.

Comment: Really? I think they both sound strange. I'd expect 'Experiencing Mediterranean cuisine in Oia is a must'.